# How can I make sliding looking webpages

Tags: navigation

I just started with html and css. I was wondering if anyone can tell me how to make a website such as http://celebratedesign.org/

I am looking for tutorials explaining how to make websites that almost look like a slideshow. You can navigate left and right and also up and down. I could not google successfully for tutorials since I do not know the name of the technique. Does this have a name like parallax?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can search with "jquery smooth scroll" words on google, i found one tutorial, i hope it will help you :

- [1]: http://www.queness.com/post/356/create-a-vertical-horizontal-and-diagonal-sliding-content-website-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

you can google Horizontally Scrolling Sites to find examples

here's a good demo
http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/06/02/smooth-vertical-or-horizontal-page-scrolling-with-jquery/

you can check out a site that i did
http://www.aandac.com/

here's a list of some examples
http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-horizonal-scroll-demos-plugins/